# Почему footer занимает место всего main

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, frontend

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Доходит до конца `main`, не поддается `padding`'у и `margin`'y.

Comment: Скорее всего в main есть float'ы и нужно сделать clearfix

Comment: Добавьте для `footer` css-свойство `clear:both;`

Comment: слишком мало данных. Покажите фрагменты кода css (именно фрагменты body, html, footer)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как всегда прижимать footer к низу экрана?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/546490/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-footer-%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b7%d1%83-%d1%8d%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не очистили поток:

```
main:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

Или:

```
main {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```